# Outlook program to move Attachments to SubFolder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, outlook-2007

I have written this small program in VS2010 to run on Outlook 2007.

It works for a standard read through of the Inbox, but I cannot get it to correctly point to other Folders, I am getting a "COMException was unhandled by user code" error that says "The operation failed. An object could not be found." ...

I have included a screenshot of my Outlook structure if it helps ...

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class ThisAddIn
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
End Sub
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
End Sub
Private Sub Application_Startup() Handles Application.Startup

    Dim MyApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
    Dim MyNS As Outlook.NameSpace = MyApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim MyInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = MyNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim MyEmails As Integer = MyInbox.Items.Count
    Dim MyEMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MyCount As Integer
    Dim MySubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = MyNS.Folders("Kickabout") **<<< Error occurs here**

    For MyCount = MyEmails To 1 Step -1
        MyEMail = MyInbox.Items(MyCount)
        If MyEMail.SenderEmailAddress = "MrX@abc.com" Then
            If MyEMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                MySubFolder = MyNS.Folders("Kickabout\Attachments")
            End If
            MyEMail.Move(MySubFolder)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

[image: My Outlook Structure]

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and setting a breakpoint at the `Dim MySubFolder ...` line and expanding the `MyNs.Folders` tree to see what is in there? In the Exchange Web Services I don't think it keys them by name, but rather by ID and you have to use a separate function to find them by name.

Comment: Yes, I was using the debugger & getting nowhere, spectacularly !!! However, I found a solution in Sue Mosher's old site, www.outlookcode.com & you are right, I needed a function, I'll put the code in now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved this myself ... if anybody is interested in the future, you have to be quite explicit in setting up the path & need a Function to do so, here is the code ...

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class ThisAddIn

Dim strFolderPath As String

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
End Sub
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown
End Sub
Private Sub Application_Startup() Handles Application.Startup

    Dim MyApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
    Dim MyNS As Outlook.NameSpace = MyApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim MyInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = MyNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim MyEmails As Integer = MyInbox.Items.Count
    Dim MyEMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim MyCount As Integer
    Dim MySubFolder As Outlook.Folder = GetMyFolder("Outlook (Gary)\Kickabout")
    Stop
    For MyCount = MyEmails To 1 Step -1
        MyEMail = MyInbox.Items(MyCount)
        If MyEMail.SenderEmailAddress = "MrX@abc.com" Then
            If MyEMail.Attachments.Count &gt; 0 Then
                MySubFolder = GetMyFolder("Outlook (Gary)\Kickabout\Attachments")
            End If
            MyEMail.Move(MySubFolder)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetMyFolder(FolderPath)
    ' folder path needs to be something like 
    '   "Public Folders\All Public Folders\Company\Sales"
    Dim aFolders
    Dim fldr
    Dim i
    Dim objNS

    On Error Resume Next
    strFolderPath = Replace(FolderPath, "/", "\")
    aFolders = Split(FolderPath, "\")

    'get the Outlook objects
    ' use intrinsic Application object in form script
    objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'set the root folder
    fldr = objNS.Folders(aFolders(0))

    'loop through the array to get the subfolder
    'loop is skipped when there is only one element in the array
    For i = 1 To UBound(aFolders)
        fldr = fldr.Folders(aFolders(i))
        'check for errors
        'If Err() &lt;&gt; 0 Then Exit Function
    Next
    GetMyFolder = fldr

    ' dereference objects
    objNS = Nothing
End Function
End Class
```